# How do I get the path of the current php file relative to the web root folder and not to the system root folder?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Some years ago I developed a web app which contained the following code in a php file located in the root folder of the app:

```
define('APP_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . DIR_SEP);
```

This was to allow the app to be installed in any sub directory of the web docs folder and not necessarily directly in the web root itself, so that the app had a base path from which to dynamically calculate any other paths used in the app.

My test system back then was an Xampp installation running on Windows 7. I no longer have that system, but I believe the path to the htdocs folder was `C:\xampp\htdocs` and my app was contained in `C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheets`. On that system, the value of `APP_ROOT` was `timesheets/`, exactly as I wanted.

I know that the customer ran the app on a Linux server and I believe the app was installed in `/var/www/timesheets/`. So the value of `APP_ROOT` was `timesheets/`. I know this worked correctly because he never needed to modify my code.

I am now trying to use the same code again, but my test system is Ubuntu 20.04 with Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.4. The value I am getting in `APP_ROOT` is `/var/www/html/timesheets/`, which is causing all my dynamic path calculations to be wrong.

I have tried setting `doc_root` and `open_basedir` in `php.ini`, but I am still getting the full absolute path. I think this must be to do with the server or php configuration, but I have searched the web and cannot find how to correct it.

Comment: I think your approach is wrong: adapt _APP_ROOT_ to your current installation, that's why it's there in the first place. The code _dirname(\_\_FILE\_\_)_ is the part to adjust or replace – I would not change php.ini for defining a root path for an application.

Comment: Thank you @lukas.j - I may end up having to do this, but my original intention was to be able to drop the app folder into any location within the web docs directory and have it "just work" without having to configure that bit.

Comment: There is no way – google for "app root" and "php" or "apache" on stackoverflow – to have a once for all solution for this. There are several 1.000 question about that. You can meddle with Apache, with php.ini, etc., but the most simple solution is to define something like APP_ROOT manually, and it can be _dirname(__FILE__)_ and this will often just work. But if not, just hard-code it.